# mod_rewrite doesn't execute specific redirects on XAMPP - conflict with DirectoryIndex?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

We're trying to set up a local development XAMPP machine (Apache2, on Windows 8).

All mod_rewrite directives work fine, except one specific kind of directive: 
We try to redirect a request for some directories to a specific file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ add_survey.php [QSA,L]
```

`index.php` is served instead.
We also tried `^.?$`, `^$`, `/*` but none of these worked.

This works though (but is too inclusive)

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ add_survey.php [QSA,L]
```

I checked the usual suspects (for me), i.e. `Options -Multiviews` and `Options -Indexes`, my colleague is now playing with [mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html), though I don't really see why it would be the culprit.

To clarify our use case:
Requests to `/survey/` should go to `add_survey.php`, while all other requests go to e.g. `/survey/SURVEYNAME/upload` and in this context the `index.php` file is served as `/survey/SURVEYNAME/`.

Basically all files are structured under the specific available surveys, the only file that can be called without a specific available survey is the one which allows you to create a new one.

```
/survey/               #-> add new survey, e.g. NAME (/survey/add_survey.php)
/survey/NAME/          #-> manage existing survey NAME (/survey/index.php?survey_name=NAME)
/survey/NAME/results   #-> view results in NAME (/survey/results.php?survey_name=NAME)
```

Comment: Accepted the given answer as it circumvents the problem, but I'd still like to know what causes the difference between XAMPP and other stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** add 
`DirectoryIndex disabled`

I made a pull request for your convenience ;) https://github.com/rubenarslan/formr.org/pull/82

A little late, but i stubled into this problem today not on XAMPP but Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 ...

After looking at the debugging output of Apache/rewrite it looks like Apache is trying index files instead of using the correct rewrite. So my solution ( or more likely workaround :) is to disable DirectoryIndex for the survey and run directory:

`/webroot/admin/run/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ add_run.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ index.php?run_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ $2.php?run_name=$1 [QSA,L]
    # on HU subdomain
#   RewriteBase /survey/admin/run/
</IfModule>
```

`/webroot/admin/survey/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ add_survey.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ index.php?study_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ $2.php?study_name=$1 [QSA,L]
    # on HU subdomain
#   RewriteBase /survey/admin/survey/
</IfModule>
```

For those of you who are into this kind of kinky stuff and maybe can help gaining deeper understanding - the debug logs:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/ -> 
applying pattern '^/?$' to uri ''
rewrite '' -> 'add_survey.php'
add per-dir prefix: add_survey.php -> /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/add_survey.php
```

looks fine... but wait...

```
strip document_root prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/add_survey.php -> /admin/survey/add_survey.php
internal redirect with /admin/survey/add_survey.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

now let's just try index.html instead

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.html -> index.html
applying pattern '^/?$' to uri 'index.html'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.html -> index.html
applying pattern '^/?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.html'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.html -> index.html
applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.html'
pass through /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.html
```

and .cgi ... not seen this for some time...

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.cgi -> index.cgi
applying pattern '^/?$' to uri 'index.cgi'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.cgi -> index.cgi
applying pattern '^/?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.cgi'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.cgi -> index.cgi
applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.cgi'
pass through /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.cgi
```

and .pl ...

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.pl -> index.pl
applying pattern '^/?$' to uri 'index.pl'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.pl -> index.pl
applying pattern '^/?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.pl'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.pl -> index.pl
applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.pl'
pass through /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.pl
```

and last but not least .php ... oohh ... look... index.php...

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^/?$' to uri 'index.php'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^/?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.php'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'index.php'
pass through /var/www/formr/webroot/admin/survey/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in `/survey/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex add_survey.php
```

**EDIT:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex add_survey.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /survey/

RewriteRule ^/?$ add_survey.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ $2.php?study_name=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ index.php?study_name=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: No, I can't. I will specify in the question, that we're also using the `index.php` file, but in a different context, so I can't just redirect requests to `index.php`.

Comment: This is not redirecting to `index.php` but if post your current rules I can probably understand better.

Comment: Is `/survey/` a real directory

Comment: No, it is redirecting requests TO `index.php`, that's the problem. We are using `index.php` too though, have changed my question accordingly. Either way, I'd like to understand why XAMPP behaves differently. Yes, `survey` is a real directory, so index.php is its DirectoryIndex.

Comment: I have forwarded it to my co-worker, thanks. Do you know why this discrepancy between Xampp and our other Apache2 installations might occur?

Comment: Actually I have also notices XAMPP behaving differently (but it is usually RewriteBase related issues)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this doesn't work either. It must be something about requests to the directory taking precedence over rewrites, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Still `index.php`. I should repeat: All other rewrites work well without RewriteBase, so it really seems to be some sort of conflict with the DirectoryIndex. I've even diffed the httpd.conf from a working and non-working install, but could not find the culprit.

Comment: ok try this edited line in `/survey/.htaccess` (not in root .htaccess)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a solution in our usecase. Then we would lose the ability to go to `/survey/SURVEYNAME`. I could of course simply rename `add_survey.php` to `index.php` but I'd rather fix our local server config.

Comment: Why would you loose that ability I cannot understand. Probably you have some rules in `/survey/` directory not shown here in question?

Comment: The question now illustrates the usecase more clearly. Yes, I have a lot more rules, but the above is the first and it has the [L] flag.

Comment: Having a rule with `L` wont help in that case and sorry I still don't see any rules in your question.

Comment: Why wouldn't that help? The complete [.htaccess](https://github.com/rubenarslan/formr/blob/master/webroot/admin/survey/.htaccess) is here, but I really don't think it matters.

Comment: Because `L` flag does not stop looping of rewrite engine. Examining your htaccess